# How do I create a class where instantiation only happens if certain conditions are met?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, instance

Let's say I have this class:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

If I want to instantiate `Person` I can do:

```
me = Person("António")
```

But what if I only want to instantiate `Person` if `name` has type `str`?
I tried this:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        if type(name) == str:
            self.name = name
```

But then when I do:

```
me = Person("António")
print(me.name)

you = Person(1)
print(you.name)
```

I get this:

[image]

So all that's happening is:

- If `name` is `str`, the instance has a `.name` method
- If `name` is not `str`, the instance has no `.name` method

But what I actually want, is to stop instantiation all together if name is not an `str`.
In other words, I want it to be impossible to create an object from the `Person` class with a non `str` `name`.

How can I do that?

Comment: @Sweeper Maybe that would work, I dunno. But ideally I would like to print something like "Failed Instantiation. Given name is not str". But yeah I guess that would be one way of doing it. But where in the code would I even raise the error?

Comment: In the `else` branch of your `if` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a factory that checks the parameters, and returns a `Person` object if everything is fine, or raises an error:

maybe something line this:

```
class PersonNameError(Exception):
    pass

class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None

def person_from_name(name: str) -> Person:
    """Person factory that checks if the parameter name is valid
    returns a Person object if it is, or raises an error without 
    creating an instance of Person if not.
    """
    if isinstance(name, str):
        p = Person()
        p.name = name
        return p
    raise PersonNameError('a name must be a string')

p = person_from_name('Antonio')
```

Whereas:

```
p = person_from_name(123)   # <-- parameter name is not a string
```

throws an exception:

```
PersonNameError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-a23e22774881> in <module>
     14 
     15 p = person_from_name('Antonio')
---> 16 p = person_from_name(123)

<ipython-input-41-a23e22774881> in person_from_name(name)
     11         p.name = name
     12         return p
---> 13     raise PersonNameError('a name must be a string')
     14 
     15 p = person_from_name('Antonio')

PersonNameError: a name must be a string
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure, this seems like the best solution. I tried it, and it works. Thanks. Just one thing, aren't you missing the "name" parameter in the "Person" class constructor? Beacuse I had to add that to your code in order to get it to work...

Comment: You could indeed have `Person` accept parameters, but my preference is not to: I designed the `__init__` method to not take any parameter, and initialize the attributes to `None`, in order to delegate all the instance construction work to the factory.

Comment: I can accept your answer, no problem. But I just wanted to make sure of this before I do it: Doesn't your code need the "name" parameter in the "Person" constructor?

Comment: As explained in my first comment, you could, but my preference is not to. `Person.__init__(self)` does not take arguments (other than `self`), and the attributes are initialized to None in `Person.__init__`

Answer (score 0):

How about :

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        if type(name) == str:
            self.name = name
        else: 
            raise Exception("name attribute should be a string")
```

Comment: I tried it with this, and it kinda works. But I'm not sure if this is stopping instantiation, or if instantiation still occurs, though anytime the instance is called an error is raised.

Comment: Yes, it stops the instantiation , Try `_p = Person(1)` and then try to access `_p`, you would see that it's not defined

Comment: ```ok
António
ok
Traceback (most recent call last):
  iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
    exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 13, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 7, in __init__
Exception: name attribute should be a string

[Program finished] ``` doesn't work ```class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        print("ok")
        if type(name) == str:
            self.name = name
        else: 
            raise Exception("name attribute should be a string") ```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `factory design pattern`. You can read more about it [here](https://realpython.com/factory-method-python/). To put it simple:

Create Class/method that will check for the conditions and return new class instance only if those conditions are met.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify instantiation behaviour,
You can create a constructor,
using a class method.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        print("ok")

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, name):
        if not isinstance(name, str):
            raise ValueError(f"Expected name to be a string, got {type(name)}")
        return cls(name)
           
me = Person.create("António")
print(me.name)

you = Person.create(1)
print(you.name)
```

OK prints once proving only once instantiation

```
ok
António
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>
    start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
    exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 11, in create
ValueError: Expected name to be a string, got <class 'int'>

[Program finished]
```

Here, it's an explicit test that's being done.
Overriding **new** is very rarely needed and for everyday normal classes I think it should be avoided. Doing so keeps the class implementation simple.

```
class Test(object):
     print("ok")
     def __new__(cls, x):
         if isinstance(x, str) :           
             print(x)
         else:
             raise ValueError(f"Expected name to be a string, got {type(x)}")
 
obj1 = Test("António")

obj2 = Test(1)
```

```
ok
António
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>
    start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
    exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 10, in __new__
ValueError: Expected name to be a string, got <class 'int'>

[Program finished]
```